# Kotlin: Sealed classes with open @JvmField not allowed in the latest version: JvmField can only be applied to final property

Tags: kotlin

I have this kind of implementation but it's not allowed after bumping Kotlin to 1.6.10 and received the following error which was warning until previous version.

`Error: JvmField can only be applied to final property`

What could be the solution here? Requirement is:

1. I need @JvmField for java consumers as I don't want to refactor the code to use the setter/getter method and want to use as a field.

```
sealed class PowerTool(
    @JvmField open val name: String,
    @JvmField open val price: Double
) {
    data class CircularSaw(
        val diameter: Int,
        val cordless: Boolean,
        override val name: String,
        override val price: Double
    ) : PowerTool(name, price)

    data class DrillPress(
        val rpm: Int,
        override val name: String,
        override val price: Double
    ) : PowerTool(name, price)
}
```

Comment: All three of your classes have exactly the same structure. How exactly does `CircularSaw` differ from `DrillPress`apart from the name?

Comment: @Sweeper: Sorry for the bad example, I just wanted to keep it minimal, updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason why a property isn't be open and `JvmField` at the same time is because you can't override a field. What normally happens when you "override" a property is a new field gets declared, and its getters and setters gets overridden.

It is simple enough to mark the properties as `JvmField` - just don't redeclare and override the properties in the subclasses. Instead, just declare them as regular parameters.

```
sealed class PowerTool(
    @JvmField val name: String,
    @JvmField val price: Double
) {
    class CircularSaw(
        val diameter: Int,
        val cordless: Boolean,
        name: String,
        price: Double
    ) : PowerTool(name, price) 
    
    class DrillPress(
        val rpm: Int,
        name: String,
        price: Double
    ) : PowerTool(name, price)
}
```

This also means that you can't use data classes and has to implement `toString`/`equals`/`hashCode` explicitly, which is not shown above.

I would instead suggest that you just expose a different property to JVM:

```
// hides all the getters by marking them as JvmSynthetic.
sealed class PowerTool(
    @get: JvmSynthetic open val name: String,
    @get: JvmSynthetic open val price: Double
) {

    // this is the property you expose. lateinits are automatically fields
    // need a better name for this...
    lateinit var jvmName: String
    lateinit var jvmPrice: Double

    data class CircularSaw(
        val diameter: Int,
        val cordless: Boolean,
        @get: JvmSynthetic override val name: String,
        @get: JvmSynthetic override val price: Double
    ) : PowerTool(name, price) {
        init {
            jvmName = name
            jvmPrice = price
        }
    }

    data class DrillPress(
        val rpm: Int,
        @get: JvmSynthetic override val name: String,
        @get: JvmSynthetic override val price: Double
    ) : PowerTool(name, price) {
        init {
            jvmName = name
            jvmPrice = price
        }
    }
}
```

I tried hiding the getter and setter of the lateinit var from the Java code, but adding `JvmSynthetic` makes the field inaccessible for some reason :(

Comment: thanks for the reply, Why do you think first approach is bad? with class instead of data class? Except the toString, equals and hashCode methods what else is missing?

Comment: @sam_k There are also `copy`, and the `componentN` methods. I just think that there are too much boilerplate, and it is tricky to write them all correctly, especially when inheritance is involved. If you don’t mind those, I guess the first way is viable too. I just didn’t think anyone would want so much boilerplate.